# Change winsock API calls in a compiled binary to return 0 or -1

Tags: windows, winapi, networking

I remember that at one point I had to disable a compiled binary's ability to access the internet and I forgot how I did it.

You can't just delete the Winsock calls out of the import table, because then there will be a fatal error, but as I recall there was a way to make it so that a given function would always return 0 or -1. For example, if WSAStartup always returns -1, then that ends any further attempts to access the internet by the application.

It is possible I am mis-remembering this, and I was actually modifying a binary which had been loaded into memory, but I thought I had somehow modified a static binary on disk to reject networking API calls. How can I do this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to stop accessing the network in your code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I do not have access to the source code for this binary nor do I have the dependencies necessary to compile it even if I did have the source code.

Comment: OK. In that case why not use the firewall?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Because the firewall policies are set by IT, not by me and also other developers may need to use the modified binary and I do not want to be explaining to them how they need to configure a firewall to test the software. Also,  I would rather have the software behaving as though it were operating on an air-gapped machine, not a fire-walled machine.

Comment: Doesn't sound at all like you have got the right solution here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am kind of hoping to get an answer to my question as asked, and not having to write paragraphs justifying my development strategies to people who assume I don't know what I am doing.

Comment: What if the module loads another module that does the access. There are all sorts of issues with your intended hack. And what if you start disabling things and the program throws an error and does not recover. We are missing all the important details.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is presumably that the import table refers not to just `WSAStartup` but to `Ws2_32.dll : WSAStartup, ...`. You can't patch the latter part (unlikely to find a convenient function in `WS2_32.dll`), but you definitely can patch the DLL name itself.

Now this affects all functions from that DLL, but it doesn't mean your replacement DLL has to replace all functions. Most functions could be **forwarded**, i.e. `Wsprox.Dll:Foo` forwards to `Ws2_32.Dll:Foo`.

But in this case, you could probably just stub every function. The function signatures are irrelevant for any function but `WSAStartup`. The loader just has to have entries. Heck, with some hacking you could make all function names synonyms of `WSAStartup`. Just put `Foo=WSAStartup` in the export list.

Comment: Right, but I was hoping to avoid writing a stub function or ws2_32.dll replacement. If there was another function that takes the same argument widths as WSAStartup and always returns -1, then obviously you could point it in the import table to that function, but I do not think there is one and creating an alternative version of ws2_32.dll to contain such an export would be a nuisance.

Comment: If you don't write a replacement DLL, or write a network filter driver, or use a firewall, then patching the imports table is your only option left. Since you don't have source code, write a separate launcher app that launches the main app and injects code into it to patch the table at startup.